# What is the equivalent of the VB6 function String$(number, character) in PHP

Tags: php, vb6

The function is described [here](http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/vb6-string-functions) and basically what it does is makes a string which contains a number of characters, like for example

```
strTest = String$(5, "a")
```

and the result would be a string with 5 characters of letter 'a'

```
strTest = "aaaaa"
```

Now, don't get me wrong, I can easily make the for loop in PHP to accomplish this, but I was wondering if a function like this already exists in the PHP core.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes look into [`str_repeat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php) function:

```
echo str_repeat('a', 5); // aaaaa
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is one: [`str_repeat`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php). Example:

```
$strTest = str_repeat('a', 5);
```

Answer (score 4):

there's str_repeat function in PHP;

```
$strTest = str_repeat("a",5);
```

source : http://www.php.net/manual/tr/function.str-repeat.php